# Lock a specific UIViewController in Landscape mode + Force landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a specific UIViewController which I want to lock/force it orientation to Landscape only.

This is what I did so far, but without any success.... I'm trying to get this working for iOS 6 & 7.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{

// Return YES for supported orientations
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

 }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

 return YES;

 }

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
if([AppConst isIPad]){
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

//not ios6

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if([AppConst isIPad]){
    return YES;
}
return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: How you presenting this `UIViewController` ? means using `UINavigtaion` ?

Answer (score 0):

The method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in iOS 6. You want to use the method supportedInterfaceOrientations instead. If you also want to run on iOS 5 or earlier then you need to implement both methods.

You should also implement the method shouldAutorotate.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove all those methods in your view controller and use this method

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
 [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]
                            forKey:@"orientation"];}
```

Happy Coding